# How to post json body to php api in flutter?

Tags: php, flutter, dart

I tried to post a JSON body to PHP API like this:

```
var response = await http.post(
   Uri.parse("https://..."),
   body: {
     "orders": [
       {"id": 253, "userId": 13, "quantity": 2, "productId": 1},
       {"id": 257, "userId": 13, "quantity": 1, "productId": 3}
     ]
   });
```

and in the API I tried to access the variable like this

```
$data=$_POST["orders"];
echo $data[0]["id"];
```

but it always get the the error **Undefined index**
can anyone help me please? I'm a flutter newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are passing a raw data to your `request` then you have to `encode` that to `json` before passing. Try code below :

```
var response = await http.post(
   Uri.parse("https://..."),
   body: jsonEnocde(
       {
         "orders": [
       {"id": 253, "userId": 13, "quantity": 2, "productId": 1},
       {"id": 257, "userId": 13, "quantity": 1, "productId": 3}
     ]
   }
));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try next code on your server side (PHP):

```
<?php
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$data=$request["orders"];
echo $data[0]["id"];
```